# Is the IntersectionObserver messing with the nav bar on load?

Tags: javascript

What's going:

No background-color is my desired state of the nav:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcc4A.png

But randomly the dark background renders:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0KGA.png

Or, also randomly, white background color renders:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PgPt.png

I've tried to implement IntersectionObserver to track a div in one of the sections (below the fold) to toggle between the dark and light class

```js
let observerSecTwoTop = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  if (entries[0].boundingClientRect.bottom < 0) {
    nav.classList.remove('solid__background__light');
    nav.classList.add('solid__background__dark');
    navMenuItem.forEach(e => e.classList.add('nav__links__dark'));
  } else if (entries[0].boundingClientRect.bottom > 0) {
    nav.classList.add('solid__background__light');
    nav.classList.remove('solid__background__dark');
    navMenuItem.forEach(e => e.classList.remove('nav__links__dark'));
  }
});

let observerSecTwoBottom = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  if (entries[0].boundingClientRect.bottom < 0) {
    nav.classList.add('solid__background__light');
    nav.classList.remove('solid__background__dark');
    navMenuItem.forEach(e => e.classList.remove('nav__links__dark'));
  } else if (entries[0].boundingClientRect.bottom > 0) {
    nav.classList.remove('solid__background__light');
    nav.classList.add('solid__background__dark');
    navMenuItem.forEach(e => e.classList.add('nav__links__dark'));
  }
});
observerSecTwoTop.observe(document.querySelector('#top--track'));
observerSecTwoBottom.observe(document.querySelector('#bottom--track'));
```

#top--track and #bottom--track are the two divs I'm tracking to toggle the nav bar colors when scroll gets to specific point in the page.

Here's the page itself: https://tombrewsviews.github.io/portfolio/

The repo is public here: https://github.com/tombrewsviews/portfolio
I appreciate any help or explanation on what am I missing here

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by adding additional check is the Observer isIntersecting with the track element. What I think was happening, an initial load was also counted as an event trigger and running through the function.

```
else if (
entries[0].boundingClientRect.bottom > 0 &&
entries[0].isIntersecting
```